# How do I achieve a continuous menu option in action bar in every page

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

How do I achieve a continuous menu option(3 dots)in action bar in every page(each activity)? Meaning those 3 dots should appear on top of (action bar) in every page so I can directly access menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a basic `ToolbarActivity` and extends it whenever you want the overflow menu (3 dots).

First, create an activity named `ToolbarActivity` and add a `Toolbar` to it, you can find the details from [Android Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up). In short, you should specify a "NoActionBar" theme which get rid of the default `ActionBar` and make your own using the `ToolBar`:

> In the app manifest, set the  element to use one of
>   appcompat's NoActionBar themes. Using one of these themes prevents the
>   app from using the native ActionBar class to provide the app bar. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> <application
>     android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
>     />
> ```

And we can use a `ViewStub` in our `ToolbarActivity` to take care of the sub activities' content layout.

The layout xml `activity_toolbar.xml` may like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And `ToolbarActivity.java`:

```
public class ToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_toolbar);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        ViewStub stub = findViewById(R.id.content);
        stub.setLayoutResource(layoutResID);
        stub.inflate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                toast("Up");
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.home:
                toast("Home");
                return true;
            case R.id.search:
                toast("Search");
                return true;
            case R.id.favorites:
                toast("Favorites");
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void toast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Then, if an `Activity` need the overflow menu, just extends `ToolbarActivity`:

```
public class SecondActivity extends ToolbarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        setTitle("Second Activity");
    }
}
```

You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/duanhong169/ToolbarActivity).